# Disable disk spindown with sdparm?

Tags: linux, usb-drive, scsi, hdparm

I'm using USB drive sat controller so hdparm doesn't fully work for me. How can I disable spindown with sdparm? (equivalent of -B 255, -S 0)

```
lapsio@nuc ~> sudo hdparm -I /dev/sdb

/dev/sdb:

ATA device, with non-removable media
        Model Number:       ST2000VN004-2E4164                      
        Serial Number:      W524Z4J7
        Firmware Revision:  SC60    
        Transport:          Serial, SATA 1.0a, SATA II Extensions, SATA Rev 2.5, SATA Rev 2.6, SATA Rev 3.0
Standards:
        Used: unknown (minor revision code 0x001f) 
        Supported: 9 8 7 6 5 
        Likely used: 9
Configuration:
        Logical         max     current
        cylinders       16383   16383
        heads           16      16
        sectors/track   63      63
        --
        CHS current addressable sectors:    16514064
        LBA    user addressable sectors:   268435455
        LBA48  user addressable sectors:  3907029168
        Logical  Sector size:                   512 bytes
        Physical Sector size:                  4096 bytes
        Logical Sector-0 offset:                  0 bytes
        device size with M = 1024*1024:     1907729 MBytes
        device size with M = 1000*1000:     2000398 MBytes (2000 GB)
        cache/buffer size  = unknown
        Form Factor: 3.5 inch
        Nominal Media Rotation Rate: 5900
Capabilities:
        LBA, IORDY(can be disabled)
        Queue depth: 32
        Standby timer values: spec'd by Standard, no device specific minimum
        R/W multiple sector transfer: Max = 16  Current = ?
        Advanced power management level: disabled
        Recommended acoustic management value: 128, current value: 128
        DMA: mdma0 mdma1 *mdma2 udma0 udma1 udma2 udma3 udma4 udma5 udma6 
             Cycle time: min=120ns recommended=120ns
        PIO: pio0 pio1 pio2 pio3 pio4 
             Cycle time: no flow control=120ns  IORDY flow control=120ns
Commands/features:
        Enabled Supported:
           *    SMART feature set
                Security Mode feature set
           *    Power Management feature set
           *    Write cache
           *    Look-ahead
           *    Host Protected Area feature set
           *    WRITE_BUFFER command
           *    READ_BUFFER command
           *    DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
                Advanced Power Management feature set
                Power-Up In Standby feature set
           *    SET_FEATURES required to spinup after power up
                SET_MAX security extension
           *    48-bit Address feature set
           *    Device Configuration Overlay feature set
           *    Mandatory FLUSH_CACHE
           *    FLUSH_CACHE_EXT
           *    SMART error logging
           *    SMART self-test
           *    Media Card Pass-Through
           *    General Purpose Logging feature set
           *    64-bit World wide name
                Write-Read-Verify feature set
           *    WRITE_UNCORRECTABLE_EXT command
           *    {READ,WRITE}_DMA_EXT_GPL commands
           *    Segmented DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
                unknown 119[6]
           *    Gen1 signaling speed (1.5Gb/s)
           *    Gen2 signaling speed (3.0Gb/s)
           *    Gen3 signaling speed (6.0Gb/s)
           *    Native Command Queueing (NCQ)
           *    Phy event counters
           *    READ_LOG_DMA_EXT equivalent to READ_LOG_EXT
                DMA Setup Auto-Activate optimization
                Device-initiated interface power management
                Software settings preservation
                unknown 78[7]
                unknown 78[11]
           *    SMART Command Transport (SCT) feature set
           *    SCT Write Same (AC2)
           *    SCT Error Recovery Control (AC3)
           *    SCT Features Control (AC4)
           *    SCT Data Tables (AC5)
                unknown 206[7]
                unknown 206[12] (vendor specific)
Security: 
        Master password revision code = 65534
                supported
        not     enabled
        not     locked
        not     frozen
        not     expired: security count
                supported: enhanced erase
        248min for SECURITY ERASE UNIT. 248min for ENHANCED SECURITY ERASE UNIT.
Logical Unit WWN Device Identifier: 5000c500a81be2ef
        NAA             : 5
        IEEE OUI        : 000c50
        Unique ID       : 0a81be2ef
Checksum: correct
lapsio@nuc ~> sudo hdparm -S 0 /dev/sdb

/dev/sdb:
 setting standby to 0 (off)
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 01 00 00 00 00 0a 00 00 00 00 00 1d 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
lapsio@nuc ~> sudo hdparm -B 255 /dev/sdb

/dev/sdb:
 setting Advanced Power Management level to disabled
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 01 00 00 00 00 0a 00 00 00 00 00 1d 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
 APM_level      = off
lapsio@nuc ~> sudo sdparm --set SCT=100000 /dev/sdb

    /dev/sdb: ST2000VN  004-2E4164        0117
lapsio@nuc ~>
```

However I can't pass 0 to SCT (which is claimed to be -S equivalent). And still I don't know about -B.

Comment: i think `sudo sdparm –clear STANDBY /dev/sde` is what I'm looking for but I didn't check efficiency of this command yet.